# how to allow access only to specific and public schemas in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Existing postrgrsql 8.4+ database contains common and multiple company data.

common data is in public schema.
company specific data in schemas  company1, company2 and company3
Those schemas contain tables with same name and same structure for every company.
All object in database are owned by db_owner

Database is accessed using ODBC by number of users. Every user has its own name and 
Currently is member of db_owner . So every user has access to all company schemas.
This should changed.

User rights are described in table public.kasutaja :

```
create table kasutaja (
kasutaja char(10) primary key,  -- postgres user name
allowedcompanies  char(30)  -- comma separated list of allowed companies
)
```

For example,

User1  has access to Company1 and public schema
User2  has access to Company1, Company2 and public schema
User3  has access to Company3 and public schema
User4  has access to all schemas.

this is described in kasutaja table as

```
insert into kasutaja values ('user1', '1');
insert into kasutaja values ('user2', '1,2');
insert into kasutaja values ('user3', '3');
insert into kasutaja values ('user4', null);
```

How to restrict access for some company schemas only for some users?
Which methods should used for this ? 
Should I ceate additional schemas db_public_owner,
db_company1_owner, db_company2_owner and db_company3_owner and grant access for users to those schemas.

How to create script with applies rights defined in kasutaja table to users user1 .. user4 users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select 
    kasutaja,
    rtrim(
        'public,' ||
            coalesce(
                regexp_replace(
                    allowedcompanies, '(\d+)', 'company\1', 'g'),
            ''),
        ',') companies
from kasutaja
```

gives:

```
kasutaja  companies
user1     public,company1
user2     public,company1,company2
user3     public,company3
user4     public
```

In anonymous code block you can walk on this result in loop and execute apprioriate revoke and grant:

```
do $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select 
            kasutaja,
            rtrim(
                'public,' ||
                    coalesce(
                        regexp_replace(
                            allowedcompanies, '(\d+)', 'company\1', 'g'),
                    ''),
                ',') companies
        from kasutaja
    loop
        execute format(
            'revoke all on all tables in schema company1,company2,company3 from %s',
            rec.kasutaja);
        execute format(
            'grant all on all tables in schema %s to %s',
            rec.companies, rec.kasutaja);
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Use e.g. `grant insert, delete, update` (or whatever you need) instead of `grant all`.

---

Anonymous code block was introduced in Postgres 9.0. In 8.4 you have to use a function instead:

```
create function set_privileges()
returns void language plpgsql as $$
...
end $$;

select set_privileges();
```